# Requests POST encoding with python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, python-requests

I'm posting this character "ç" that is usually sent through a form, to a website I don't control. I'm having trouble with the encoding of the data. Trying to send data without encoding it to utf-8 produces this error (correction: this error was for another special character, mistake!):

```
File "D:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1181, in _send_request
body = body.encode('iso-8859-1')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u0192' in position 512: ordinal not in range(256)
```

I'm reading the data from a .csv file saved with utf-8 encoding (is this part of the problem?)

After using .encode('utf-8') and a bit of trial and error:

Posting this: ç Displays on their site as: Ã§

Posting this: Ã§ Displays on their site as: ÃƒÂ§

Sample of shortened code:

```
headers = {
'Accept' : 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
}

data = {
"info" : "ç"
}

r = requests.post('www.urlgoeshere.com', headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data,ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8'))
```

Anyone got any tips on how I can send these special characters and have them display correctly? Or should I just give up and edit them all out. Their website form manages it anyway so I would like to as well.

Edit for more complete .csv code:

```
with open('data.csv', newline='') as dataFile:
dataReader = csv.reader(dataFile)
for row in dataReader:
    data = {
    "values":{
    "title_id":row[1],
    "title":row[0],
    "other stuff":[{"foo":"bar",
    "too":"foobar"}]}
    }
```

It's in that loop that i do the request as well. Data.csv is a comma-delimited file saved as utf-8.

Comment: Apparently you are sending a ISO-8859-1 character. Try "info" : u"ç".  Also look if the file containing your code is UTF-8 encoded

Comment: The code and the datafile are both utf-8. Have to leave for a while though. Be back later (and thanks for the help sofar).

Comment: The line  `body = body.encode('iso-8859-1')` is from httplib, that is trying to encode the body of the requests  a iso-8859-1, add the actual code

Comment: Added the code now. As far as i can understand it is that it only accepts text that can be iso-8859-1 encoded. And the special characters can't be represented using that encoding afaik.

Comment: It dos if you pass a str type, what you want to pass is bytes, I was also asking about your code that reads froma csv not httplib

Comment: I see. That might be useful then. I added the correct code above now anyway :) Thanks.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I fiddled around with this a bit and it seems this is working. Is it what you had in mind? `r = requests.post('www.urlgoeshere.com', headers=headers, verify=False, data=json.dumps(data,ensure_ascii=False).encode('latin-1'))` Since encoding it as utf-8 seemed to double encode it, i changed it to latin-1 since it was supposed to be that. Just want to make sure im not messing anything up. Also, if you want to turn this into an answer, i'll choose it and give you rep if you wish :)

Comment: If you opened the file with `"rb"` you would already have bytes, what I was getting at is pretty much what you have done, if you look at the post example in the urllib.request docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib-examples, you can see the logic is the same, you pass bytes.If you got a working solution then you can fire ahead and write an answer yourself and accept it, you may even get an upvote ;)

Comment: Also you are not double encoding, if you have a unicode str `.encode("utf-8")` would encode to a bytes string. `"ç".encode("utf-8") -> b'\xc3\xa7'`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I made a mistake. Seems `ç` can actually be represented using latin-1 (looking at the character set. Not sure why it complained earlier then). Now i'm having problems with characters like `™` and `’`. These can't be represented using Latin-1. Guess i made the question too specific. Do you see any solution here? If i encode them as utf-8 to turn it into bytes, they will arrive and the website will display them incorrectly. I just can't wrap my head around this anymore it seems.

Comment: Without "ensure_ascii=False" it allows me to post it and `™` displays as `â„¢` on their site. Same thing happens if i encode as latin-1 or utf-8.

Comment: @raecer, `'\u0192'` is a latin-1 encoded  small f with a hook,  what happens if you open the file adding `encoding="utf-8"`? Also can you share the url?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Hey, that actually seemed to do it :) Opening the file like that and encoding it as utf8 in the request made it display correctly on the website! It is for a website called indiegala that has a really awkward way of posting steamkeys as trades so i thought i would streamline the process even if its probably frowned upon there. Thanks a lot anyway, that seemed to do it :)

Comment: No  worries, you file was being opened with the wrong encoding, it is using whatever is the preferred encoding on your OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer to this question was that i was opening the datafile without specifying the encoding. Had i added the `encoding="utf-8"` to the open function, and encoded the request as utf-8 this would have been solved rather quickly.